# Abstract private attributes in Python

Tags: python, python-typing

In Python >= 3.12, how do I declare private attributes in abstract classes?

The following snippet should declare an abstract attribute. Though, from my understanding, this actually forces a getter on non-abstract subclasses (which produces the same behavior):

```py
class MyAbstractClass(ABC):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def my_prop(self) -> MyType:
        pass

class Concrete(MyAbstractClass):
    def __init__(self, param: MyType):
        self._my_prop = param

    @property
    def my_prop(self) -> MyType:
        return self._my_prop
```

But how do I declare only abstract private attributes, *without* a getter?

```py
class MyAbstractClass(ABC):

    # @?
    __my_prop: MyType # <- should be an abstract private attribute
```

I'm afraid this is a misunderstanding on my part and Python organizes this differently than in other languages. I searched the `abc` docs but could not find a satisfying answer.

Edit: Thanks for your help! I know that "private properties" are not actually private in Python. Though this is not what I am asking for. I want each inherited subclass to have this certain property. In this case it's supposed to private. As other's indicated, I might have used misleading python terminology. But what's the pythonic way?

Edit 2: I am looking for something like interfaces with the possibility to define private or readonly members.

Comment: Properties are *class* attributes and special-cased to allow them to be made abstract. You cannot define abstract instance attributes.

Comment: `__my_prop` is also not really *private*; the leading `__` defines an attribute that you cannot accidentally shadow in a child class.

Comment: Abstract private attribute is an oxymoron.  If it's private, it's supposed to be visible only to this class and no other class needs to know about it.  If it's abstract, you're forcing other classes to know about it.

Comment: I know that this wouldn't be actually private and the discrepancy of "private" and "abstract". I am just looking for a way to declare a certain property – marked "private" – with a certain type to every subclass of this abstract class.

If I understand you correct, Python does not allow me to do this, right?

Comment: I am not yet familiar with python terminology. In other words: How can I force the constructor of each subclass to contain a specific property? In this case it's just private.

Comment: Edit: this only about DX. The developer should be enforced or at least noticed by a linter/type checker that he/she is missing a certain property. This is not about a private property not actually being private.

Comment: What is special about `__my_prop` that the implementer of `my_prop` should be forced to use it?

Comment: I am certainly sure this is not the pythonic way. Nevertheless, I unintentionally have to use my concepts from other languages before acquiring new ones.

I would want to have an abstract class, that defines how a subclass should look like and behave. In my scenario, each instance of a subclass of this abstract class would be expected to contain this certain private property (though it does not need to be really private, just titled so). I can do this with public attributes – as mentioned above –, so I expected Python to offer solutions for private ones too.

Comment: There might be a better solution or a completely different approach in Python. However, I am trying to implement solutions with concepts I am familiar with. As @FrankYellin indicated, what I am asking for is contradictory. Despite this, the desired feature could be implemented in other languages – e.g. make it readonly but public.

Answer (score 0):

You could rely on python's name mangling to hide the property name by adding 2 underscores, but it's more of a contract thing, but not truly private property.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class MyAbstractClass(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def _init_my_prop(self, value):
        """
        Abstract method to initialize the private attribute __my_prop
        """
        raise NotImplementedError

class Concrete(MyAbstractClass):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self._init_my_prop(param)

    def _init_my_prop(self, value):
        self.__my_prop = value

    # We could create a getter too
    def get_my_prop(self):
        return self.__my_prop
```

Note:
The property won't be strictly private, but rather it would be hidden.
For example if one tried to instantiate and show the `__my_prop` he would get

```py
c = Concrete("hello")
print(c.__my_prop)
# Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
# AttributeError: 'Concrete' object has no attribute '__my_prop'.
# Did you mean: 'get_my_prop'?
print(c.get_my_prop())
'hello'
```

However it's possible to access `__my_prop` using the classname_propertyname, for example the following would work

```
print(c._Concrete__my_prop)
'hello'
```